# Is it best practise to always have serializer objects correspond to models in Django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Using the django rest framework, if I have, say, a view to sign a user in that requires the requestor to send the following JSON:

```
{
    "username": "johnyappleseed",
    "password": "md783bfaHVfa"
}
```

Is it within best practice to have some serializer class along the lines of:

```
class SignInSerializer (serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField( ... )
    password = serializers.CharField( ... )
```

to validate requests made by clients?

If not, how does one go about validating such requests?

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about a general authentication feature.

You can of course come up with your own solution, but there're already few libraries that will help you out with that:

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#third-party-packages

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I'm trying to get my head around Django, and I hope I'm phrasing the question properly.  If I'm using token based authentication already, and I want to make sure the client is sending the right keys in the JSON (i.e. "username", and "password") will those libraries do so?  I'm currently using Token based auth to verify users, but I need an elegant way to validate the JSON itself.